# Inserting into the db with PDO

Tags: pdo

```
    <form action="uploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" class="upload">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload</legend><br/>
            Title:  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" required> <br/><br/>
            <textarea name="description" rows="6" cols="35" maxlength="120"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" required multiple>    <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
        </fieldset>          

        <div class="bar">
            <span class="bar-fill" id="pb"><span class="bar-fill-text" id="pt"></span></span>
        </div>

        <div id="uploads" class="uploads"> 
        Uploaded file links will appear here.   
        </div> 


<?php

// configuration

$dbhost     = "localhost";

$dbname     = "blog";

$dbuser     = "root";

$dbpass     = "pass";



// database connection

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);



// new data

$name = 'name';
$mime = 'mime';
$data = 'data';
$size = 'size';
$description = 'description';
$created = 'created';
$url = 'url';


// query

$sql = "INSERT INTO videos (name,mime,data,size,description,created,url) VALUES (:name,:mime,:data,:size,:description,:created,:url)";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':name'=>$name,

              ':mime'=>$mime,

              ':data'=>$data,

              ':size'=>$size,

              ':description'=>$description,

              ':created'=>$created,

              ':url'=>$url));
?>
```

I'm not so good with PDO, I can get videos to upload to my db, but I can't take in a name or anything. It just shows: name, description, size is 0 and etc. I've watched a few tutorials, but none of them show how to add it by what the user names it or describes it as, only what they put into the values goes to the database. I've also searched around on here and many other websites, but no luck.

Comment: You're not actually using any of the user input values, just hard-coded strings...

Comment: Like I said, I'm not good with PDO. I did add an if statement though, haha. Do you know any tutorials? Helpful sites or anything

Comment: Recommendations for tutorials and other off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  There are *plenty* of introductory PHP tutorials available to get you started.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, so are you trying to pass the input fields as params for you database query? And you're having trouble doing what?

Comment: I'm trying to get the user inputs when they upload a video, I can receive the video in my db, but I can not get what the user puts as a name for it, etc. -Luís